# Remove class and style tag when window width is resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, window, screen-resolution

I would like to remove a class `showMenu` from `#menu ul` element and `#style2` tag when window size is bigger than 1000px.

My code:

```
$(function() {
  if (window.screen.width > 1000) {
    $("#menu ul").removeClass("showMenu");
    $("#menuicon").removeClass("active");
    $("#style2").remove();
  }
});
```

I don't know why it removes everything immediately, not after screen resizing to 1001px...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it checks the screen's width **only once**, after loading. To make this work every time when the screen is resized, this has to go inside `$(window).resize()`:

> **Update:** You need to check with `window.innerWidth` not with `window.screen.width`.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
      $("#menu ul").removeClass("showMenu");
      $("#menuicon").removeClass("active");
      $("#style2").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

I would also believe you wanna **revert it back** once it becomes normal:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
      $("#menu ul").removeClass("showMenu");
      $("#menuicon").removeClass("active");
      $("#style2").remove();
    } else {
      $("#menu ul").addClass("showMenu");
      $("#menuicon").addClass("active");
      $("#style2").remove(); // I don't know how to do this! `:P`
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: probably want window width , not screen width

Comment: @charlietfl Looks fine for me.

Comment: Well... Now it removes everything after every single window resize. Not after resizing window to more than 1000px.

Comment: @user4011723 There's a mistake. Updating it

Comment: @user4011723 well that's what happens when you don't provide expected behaviors

Comment: @user4011723 Check the updated answer please and tell me if it works. `:)`